# Typescript return if value is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible to return whether a value is defined (i.e. not undefined) in such a way, that the transpiler understands that it is not undefined?

To clarify my question, image this example:

```js
let myVar: MyClass | undefined = /*something*/

if(myVar) {
    myVar.foo() // this always works, because the transpiler knows that myVar will never be undefined
}
```

However, imagine that `myVar` needs to be initialized before `foo()` can be called. So the `if` statement becomes `if(myVar && myVar.isInitialized())`. But because this check needs to happen in a lot of functions, I wrote the function `isUsable()`:

```js
function isUsable(myVar: MyClass | undefined): boolean {
    return myVar && myVar.isInitialized();
}

let myVar: MyClass | undefined = /*something*/

if(isUsable(myVar)) {
    myVar.foo() // this does not work, because myVar may be undefined. I would have to use myVar?.foo() or myVar!.foo() which I want to avoid
}
```

Is it possible to define `isUsable()` in such a way, that the transpiler still understands, that `myVar` can not be undefined in the `if`-Block?

Comment: why wouldn't you just write: `if (myVar && isUsable(myVar)) {`

Comment: Why would you not want to use `myVar?.foo()` since it is exactly made for that use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a type guard, `myVar is MyClass`.

```js
function isUsable(myVar: MyClass | undefined): myVar is MyClass {
    return myVar && myVar.isInitialized();
}

let myVar: MyClass | undefined;

if(isUsable(myVar)) {
    myVar.foo(); // now it works.
}
```

since TS 3.7 you can even assert it.

```js
function isUsable(myVar: MyClass | undefined): asserts myVar is MyClass {
  if (!myVar || !myVar.isInitialized()) {
    throw new Error();
  }
}

let myVar: MyClass | undefined;

isUsable(myVar);
myVar.foo(); // now it works.
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Is there a similar solution, where myVar is not passed as a parameter, but instead is a global (global as in defined at the top level of the module) variable?

Comment: I advise you to check [the official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: Is you want `myVar` to be a global one you need to write its declaration, it's a bit different topic, you can check it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html, with its declaration you don't need even any assertion anymore.